# DIsplay all the column values of a specific row by calling the row name and not row location

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
    Animal  Number_legs  default_rank  max_rank  NA_bottom  pct_rank
0      cat          4.0           2.5       3.0        2.5     0.625
1  penguin          2.0           1.0       1.0        1.0     0.250
2      dog          4.0           2.5       3.0        2.5     0.625
3   spider          8.0           4.0       4.0        4.0     1.000
4    snake          NaN           NaN       NaN        5.0       NaN
```

Using pandas, I want to display all the values of a specific animal by calling the name and not call the location?

For example, I dont want to use this
df.loc[0,:]

instead I want to use
df.loc['cat',:] which does not work.

Can anyone help with some other method?

Comment: you could make the 'Animal' column the index and then use df.loc['cat',:]

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to replace number indexes by names.

Check this

```
df.set_index('Animal')
```

You can read more about this here:

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html

Answer (score 0):

@Jafar Hasan are you looking for something simply like this? Otherwise, set it as the index as suggested, but I personally would never do that and would just do the below.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({'Animal':['Cat', 'Bat', 'Rat'],
                   'Limbs':[4,2,4],
                   'Unique Trait' : ['Nine lives', 'Nocturnal', 'Love cheese']
                  })
df.loc[df['Animal'] == 'Cat']
```